# How to properly position elements in Android FrameLayout?

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

I am trying to overlay an ImageButton on top of a fragment of a GoogleMap. I have also tried to use the [following StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33987248/how-to-properly-position-elements-in-android-framelayout) for reference, with no luck. In order to do this, this is my xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapActivity" >

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.beckah.myapplication.Citisplore"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:background="@drawable/transit_icon"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_gravity="right|bottom" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Which produces this view: 
[image: actual view]

My goal is to position the ImageButton so it looks something like this: 
[image: desired view]

I'm also pretty certain that hard-coding the height/width of an image is not best practice.

How can I position the ImageButton more precisely?

Comment: Looks like you need a margin around the ImageButton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add some margin to this button `android:layout_margin="16dp"`

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:background="@drawable/transit_icon"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_gravity="right|bottom" />
```

Answer (score 1):

use margin right and margin bottom